# Passing value to the function

Tags: c#, linq

I want to pass the filterType to GetPeronMemberDTO, How to achieve this.

```
filters = filterItems.
    AsQueryable().
    Select(z => new Person()
    {
        Name = z.Name,
        ID = Convert.ToString(z.ID),
        FilterType = GetFilterType(Convert.ToString(z.TemplateID)),
        // TODO : How to pass the filtertype in the below function
        FilterMembers = GetPeronMemberDTO(
            Convert.ToString(z.ID), 
            searchParamDTO, 
            Convert.ToString(z.TemplateID)),
    })
```

Thanks
DS

Comment: What are `filterItems` and `searchParamDTO` and what does not work, do you get an exception?

Comment: what does `GetFilterType` and `GetPeronMemberDTO` return?

Comment: Describe your working environment a bit more detailed please.

Comment: Call `GetFilterType(...)` twice or use `let`.

Comment: Add the signature of GetPeronMemberDTO(parameters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the query syntax you can use a `let` expression:

```
filters = from z in filterItems.AsQueryable()
          let filterType = GetFilterType(Convert.ToString(z.TemplateID))
          select new Person
          {
            Name = z.Name,
            ID = Convert.ToString(z.ID),
            FilterType = filterType,
            FilterMembers = GetPeronMemberDTO(Convert.ToString(z.ID), 
              searchParamDTO, Convert.ToString(z.TemplateID), filterType)
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filters = filterItems
          .AsQueryable()
          .Select(z => new {
                Item = z,
                FilterType = GetFilterType(Convert.ToString(z.TemplateID))
          })
          .Select(z => new Person()
            {
                Name = z.Item.Name,
                ID = Convert.ToString(z.Item.ID),
                FilterType = z.FilterType,
                FilterMembers = GetPeronMemberDTO(Convert.ToString(z.Item.ID), searchParamDTO, z.FilterType),
            })
```

or use query-based syntax, like in Anders Abels answer.

Comment: This the method syntax equivalence of my query. They will be compiled exactly the same. I think that `let` is easier to read, so that's why I prefer the query syntax.

Comment: When `let` is needed I prefer query-based syntax too :) But the example was in method-based one, so I left it that way :)

Comment: +1 for creating the query using the original form. I've never really got my head around that well enough to do it.